# react/redux class component api data issue- data not fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, redux

I am creating a react native app with usring redux for state management
and the api call has session token key  when I am doing the api call its not returning could anyone help me check in this that what am I missing here.

I do mapstatoprops in component and checking but the output is undefined

---

this is mock api
header has ***sessionkey*** value

```
"data": {
        "mainperson": {
            "currentperson": {
                "id": null,
                "personkey": "32495935",
                "name": "TEST-123",
                "personkey2": "r4r34t4",

            },
            "savedperson": {
                "id": null,
                "personkey": "4343534534",
                "name": "TEST-123",
                "personkey2": "n3444",

            },
            "currentval": true
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "error": {
            "errorCode": 0,
            "errorDesc": "SUCCESSFUL"
        }
    }
}
```

---

action file

```
 export function fetchdatasfromapi(sessionkey) {
    
      return function (dispatch) {
        fetch(`url`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            sessionkey,
          },
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then((r) => {
            if (r.response.error.errorCode === -4) {
              dispatch({
                type: 'FAILCASE',
                payload: ' error,  try again',
              });
            } else {
              dispatch({
                type: 'PASSCASE',
                payload: {
                    peopledata: responseJson.data,
                },
              });
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FAILCASE', payload: error });
            dispatch({
              type: 'FAILCASE',
              payload: ' error,  try again',
            });
          });
      };
    }
```

---

reducer file

```
const initialState = {
    peopledata: {},
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}
export default function peopledatareducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
       
        case PASSCASE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                peopledata: action.data
            }
        case FAILCASE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: _`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`_ on a GET request? Why?

Comment: @Phil  was copying from another request :O

Comment: @famo can you check what response are you getting here? .then(response => response.json())

Comment: @GauravRoy 
 .then(response => {
        console.log('fsfdsfdsgfdg',response.json())
        return response.json()}) added like this

not showing up in console

Comment: :O i guess its going in catch rather than . then

Comment: api must be failing

Comment: @GauravRoy any idea how to fix the action

Comment: @GauravRoy api seems ok in postman

Comment: @famo can you do one thing? share a working example in expo snack, will check there. hope that works

Comment: some problem surely with session key i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247782/discussion-between-famo-and-gaurav-roy).